Critical Points of a Wigner function
I am interested in calculating the critical points of a Wigner function
$$
W(x,p)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left\langle x+y\middle|\rho\middle|x-y\right\rangle e^{-2ipy}\mathrm{d}y
$$
Unfortunately, my knowledge of calculus and linear algebra is only rudimentary. I know that I can do this by calculating the first and second partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $p$, but I have no idea how to evaluate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\langle x+y \middle |\rho \middle| x-y\right\rangle
$$
In particular, I am not even sure how $\left|x\right\rangle$ should look in this expression for an arbitrary $\rho$. Does it depend on the basis in which $\rho$ is written?
Aside from that, I was wondering if there is a more straightforward (established maybe? I found nothing so far) way of calculating the critical points of a Wigner function.

Differentiation of inner products is defined as follows:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \langle f(t)| g(t) \rangle = \langle f(t)| g^{\prime}(t) \rangle + \langle f^{\prime}(t)| g(t) \rangle $$
Does this help you get to your desired solution?

I'm not sure why you might be interested in $W(x,p)$ as a plain function (which it is), since it is meant to be acted on by star products of functions of x and p, unless it is inside a phase-space integral. In any case, you of course know that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\langle x+y \middle |\hat \rho \middle| x-y\right\rangle =  
 \left\langle x+y \middle |{i\over \hbar}[\hat p,\hat  \rho ] \middle| x-y\right\rangle , 
$$
and it's trivial to derive the exponential inside the integral,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}W(x,p)=\frac{-2i}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left\langle x+y\middle|\hat \rho\middle|x-y\right\rangle e^{-2ipy}y\mathrm{d}y .
$$
So it very much depends on the nature of the (operator) density matrix. For example, for the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator, a plain phase-space Gaussian when nondimensionalized, m=1, ω=1,
$$
W(x,p)={1\over \pi \hbar} e^{-{x^2+p^2 \over 2\hbar}},
$$
with trivial critical structure as a plain function in phase space.
